# Tensorflow Dynamic Padding

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to pad a tensor. In the example below I flatten the input tensor and then pad it to size 900. Padding `x` works fine when using an literal integer for the padding, e.g.:

```
num_units = 900

print('*** inputTensor')
print(inputTensor)

x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputTensor)
print('*** x before padding')
print(x)

paddings = [[0, 0], [0, 584]] # OK
x = tf.pad(x, paddings)

print('*** x after padding')
print(x)
```

Result:

```
*** inputTensor
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 79, 4), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'")
*** x before padding
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 316), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='flatten/Reshape:0', description="created by layer 'flatten'")
*** x after padding
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 900), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.compat.v1.pad/Pad:0', description="created by layer 'tf.compat.v1.pad'")
```

But it does not work if I calculate the padding value at runtime. I have tried multiple ways of setting the value to replace the `584` in the line marked `OK` above, but none work:

```
paddings = [[0, 0], [0, num_units - tf.shape(x)[1]]] # no good
paddings = [[0, 0], [0, num_units - tf.size(x)]]  # no good
```

Both of the above (and other approaches) all change the final shape of x to be (`None, None`):

```
*** x after padding
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.compat.v1.pad/Pad:0', description="created by layer 'tf.compat.v1.pad'")
```

It seems that `tf.pad` requires integer values while the calculation results are tensors. What am I missing?

***UPDATE***

Got it working using the technique in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367059/how-to-zero-pad-dense-layer-in-keras):

```
num_units = 900
print('inputTensor.shape', inputTensor.shape)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputTensor)
print('after flatten', x.shape)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([-1, 1])(x)
print('after reshape', x.shape)
pad_amount = num_units - x.shape[1]
print('pad_amount', pad_amount)
x = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding1D(padding=(0, pad_amount))(x)
print('after padding', x.shape)
x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape([-1])(x)
print('after reshape', x.shape)
```

Output:

```
inputTensor.shape (None, 79, 4)
after flatten (None, 316)
after reshape (None, 316, 1)
pad_amount 584
after padding (None, 900, 1)
after reshape (None, 900)
```

Comment: I didn't test it, but did you try [tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding2D)?

Comment: I tried `tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D` and `tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding1D` but neither worked. It seems these functions require extra dimensions which my tensor does not have. `tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D` throws this error: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer zero_padding2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 316)`. My tensor is basically a vector with shape = (batchSize, 316).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - see technique added into original question.